# WPF - Keyboard and mouse click at the same time

Tags: powershell

is it possible in PowerShell and WPF to trigger an event out of a keyboard click and a mouse click?
I have for example following button in my WPF:

```
<Button Name="button_test" Content="Test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
```

I would like to trigger to two events with it. One event with a standard mouse click:

```
$button_test.Add_Click({ #do something })
```

And something when I hold CTRL and do a mouse click on the same button.
A keyboard click I do like this

```
$window.add_KeyDown{
    param
    (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e
    )

    if($e.Key -eq 'CTRL')  { #do something else}
}
```

But I don’t know how to combine these two events. Is it even possible?

Thanks

Stephan

Comment: Just search for how to build a [PowerShell keyboard logger] or [PowerShell monitor keyboard or mouse events] and you'll have lots of examples to get you started. Just create a function, test for functionality, the assign that function to your WPF object event.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late respond. I "solved" it with an extra variable, but I am not sure if this is the correct way, so any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
$title = "test"

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# GUI
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window_GuiManagement" Title="$title" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" 
        Width = "Auto" Height = "350.000" Visibility="Visible" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Margin="5">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
                <Button Name="button_1" Content="Button 1" />
                <Button Name="button_2" Content="Button 2"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

# Declare objects
$button_1 = $window.FindName("button_1")
$button_2 = $window.FindName("button_2")


$global:ctrl = $false

$button_1.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Button 1 clicked" })

$button_2.Add_Click({
        if($global:ctrl){
            Write-Host "do more" $ctrl
        } else {
            Write-Host "do standard" $ctrl
        }
})

$window.add_KeyDown{
    param
    (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e
    )
    #Write-Host $e.Key
    if($e.Key -eq "LeftCtrl")
    {
        return ($global:ctrl = $true)
    }
}

$window.add_KeyUp{
    param
    (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)][Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e
    )
    #Write-Host $e.Key
    if($e.Key -eq "LeftCtrl")
    {
        return ($global:ctrl = $false)
    }
}

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```